# File upload control error

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

im using a file upload control and here is my code :

```
//Uploading the image
     if (imageUpload.HasFile) 
     {
         try
         {
             if (imageUpload.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
             {
                 if (imageUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength < 102400)
                 {
                     string im = ( "~/User" +  "/" + Page.User.Identity.Name + "/" + Page.User.Identity.Name  + ".jpeg");
                     imageUpload.SaveAs(im);
                     uploadLabel.Text = "";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     uploadLabel.Text = "File size must be less than 1024 kb";
                 }
             }
             else 
             {
                 uploadLabel.Text = "File must be in jpeg/jpg format"; 
             }
         }
         catch(Exception ex) 
         {
             uploadLabel.Text = "File upload failed becuase: " + ex.Message; 
         }
     }
```

but im getting an error: 
The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path "path" is not rooted.

what am i doing wrong.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SaveAs()` requires an absolute path.

try using `Request.PhysicalApplicationPath  + "\\User"`

Comment: Just wanted to notify you that I'm undeleting your answer since @Wahtever said that this is what helped him solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `Save` method is configured to require an absolute path (starting with `X:\...`, in some drive).

You should call `Server.MapPath` to get the absolute path on disk to `~/whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

Add Server.MapPath where you declare im 
Server.MapPath gives you the absolute path.

`string im = Server.MapPath("/User") +  "/" + Page.User.Identity.Name + "/" + Page.User.Identity.Name  + ".jpeg";`

Answer (score 0):

```
 string filename = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
     if (filename != "")
        {             
            ImageName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();

            ImagePath = Server.MapPath("Images");
            SaveLocation = ImagePath + "\\" + ImageName;
            SaveLocation1 = "~/Image/" + ImageName;
            sl1 = "Images/" + ImageName;
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
         }
```

try this may be help ful.......